# inputText max length value from the properties file (for validation)

Tags: java, jsf

In one of my project i have **more than hundred input fields**. where i must have to define the max length for each input field.

I am thinking to use this max value from properties file as **max=#{properties[name.maxLength]}** so any person can change the maxLengths for fields from properties file. Is it a good idea and will it affects the page rendering time ?